# Limit Entries per Category

Tags: categories, stash, mx-jumper

I am trying to build a listing page of entries broken down by parent category.

I originally used the category archive tag but there isn't option to limit the entries per category.

I've also tried using Stash and this method marked as the answer [Listing entries, ordering by Category](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/393/listing-entries-ordering-by-category)

It works by showing all entries under each parent category, but once I throw the limit parameter in the channel entries tag it doesnt work, just shows the categories.  Also tried using MX Jumper, same result.

I found this method from Low http://gotolow.com/blog/nesting-tags-and-performance-in-ee
It works the same, but again once limit parameter is in channel tag it breaks.

However I have found that placing the category_group parameter in the channel tag that it  works, sorta.  It will show entries, but whatever the limit is instead of limit per category.

Below is my code for Stash:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="publications" disable="pagination|member_data|category_fields" dynamic="no" limit="5"}
  {exp:stash:append name="publications_{categories limit='1'}{category_id}{/categories}" parse="inward"}
    <p>{title}</p>
  {/exp:stash:append}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:channel:categories channel="publications" style="linear" disable="category_fields" show_empty="no" parent_only="yes"}
  <h3>{category_name}</h3>
  {exp:stash:get name="publications_{category_id}"}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Any thoughts on how to build out a entry list organized by category where you can set a limit of entries to show per category?

I do have Auto-Assign to Category Parents marked yes.
I've disabled extensions one at a time to see if one was causing any issues, found nothing.

**UPDATE**
I do realize that putting limit on channel tag would limit it to 5 entries no matter their categories.  Looking to limit it to 5 entries per category.

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flipping your code around like this.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="publications" dynamic="no"  disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
    {categories}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="publications_{category_id}"}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

and

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="publications" style="linear" disable="category_fields" show_empty="no" parent_only="yes"}
    <h2>{category_name}</h2>
    <ul>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="publications_{category_id}" limit="5"}
            <li>
                <h3>{title}</h3>
            </li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I just had to build the same thing:)